# Форматирование кода

Tags: c++, visual-studio, форматирование-кода

Стоит ли приводить код к виду:

```
const auto _VbFirst_ch = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(_VbFirst);
const auto _VbLast_ch  = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(_VbLast);
const auto _Count_ch   = static_cast<size_t>(_VbLast_ch - _VbFirst_ch);
const auto _ValChar    = static_cast<unsigned char>(_Val ? -1 : 0);
```

Или оставлять так:

```
const auto _VbFirst_ch = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(_VbFirst);
const auto _VbLast_ch = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(_VbLast);
const auto _Count_ch = static_cast<size_t>(_VbLast_ch - _VbFirst_ch);
const auto _ValChar = static_cast<unsigned char>(_Val ? -1 : 0);
```

И как сделать это автоматически в VS?

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/41982756/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-Visual

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52187397/7485582

Comment: Дело вкуса, не более того. Если работаете в команде - дело команды принять общее решение.

Comment: На мой вкус, когда  тип очевиден и имя не сложна (типа   `some_namespace::some_type::iterator`), то логичнее явно указать тип и не переусердствовать с `auto `. Так что, в данном случаи, для меня оба варианта плохи.